# Where do I ask a question about Russian literature?

Tags: discussion

**In general, is a question about Russian Literature on topic here?**

Here is what my question would look like:

---

I am a non-russian speaker looking for a plot summary of two books by [Vsevolod Kochetov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vsevolod_Kochetov). The books are:

*The Brothers Yershov* (also known as *Ershov Brothers*) 1958

*An Angle of Fall* 1967

---

I don't think asking about this is on-topic for Russian Language SE; and there is no Literature SE. What SE should I go to?

If not SE, any ideas on where to go?

Comment: Since no one appears to have mentioned this yet: the [Literature SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature) is now in its commitment phase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think your question would be on topic here. You could ask for an explanation of certain sentences you don't understand from the books, provided that you give the source, though. And there is no site on SE which would be helpful in this respect. If you can read Russian, try to search for the information on the net in Russian.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be on-topic only if it was written in Russian. But I gather from your question that you have translated books, so off-topic.